# How to rectify this string format error in ios

Tags: ios, json

This is my actual json response:

```
{
"x": {
"user": {
"id": 1,
"name": "a"
},
"startday": "2016-01-10",
"status": "New",
"total": 1,
"time_entries": [
{
"id": 766,
"project": {
"id": 3,
"name": "b"
},
"issue": {
"id": 4
},
"user": {
"id": 1,
"name": "c"
},
"activity": {
"id": 8,
"name": "d"
}
"hours": 1,
"comments": "",
"spent_on": "2016-01-10"
}
]
}
}
```

I created this response dynamically, like this:

```
NSString * newstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\\\"wk_time\\\":\%@\{\\\"user\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\,\\\"name\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\,\\\"startday\\\":\\\"%@\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"%@\\\",\\\"total\\\":\%@\,\\\"time_entries\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":766,\\\"project\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\,\\\"name\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\,\\\"issue\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\%@\,\\\"user\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\,\\\"name\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\,\\\"activity\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\,\\\"name\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\,\\\"hours\\\":\%@\,\\\"comments\\\":\%@\,\\\"spent_on\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\}",,,...];
```

Then, do it in prescribed format :

```
NSString * newstring1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“\"@%@\"",newstring];
NSLog(@"%@",newstring1);
```

So, the response is:

```
@"{\"x\":{\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"b\"},\"startday\":\"2016-01-10\",\"status\":\"New\",\"total\":1.0,\"time_entries\":[{\"id\":766,\"project\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"a\"},\"issue\":{\"id\":4},\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"b\"},\"activity\":{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"c\"},\"hours\":1.0,\"comments\":\"\",\"spent_on\":\"2016-01-10\"}]}}”
```

If i post this response statically like this:

```
NSString * jsoncode =@"{\"x\":{\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"b\"},\"startday\":\"2016-01-10\",\"status\":\"New\",\"total\":1.0,\"time_entries\":[{\"id\":766,\"project\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"a\"},\"issue\":{\"id\":4},\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"b\"},\"activity\":{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"c\"},\"hours\":1.0,\"comments\":\"\",\"spent_on\":\"2016-01-10\"}]}}";
NSData *objectData = [jsoncode  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
```

It gets serialized.shows the values.on this scenario.But on creating dynamically like this:

```
NSString * newstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\\\"wk_time\\\":\%@\{\\\"user\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\,\\\"name\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\,\\\"startday\\\":\\\"%@\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"%@\\\",\\\"total\\\":\%@\,\\\"time_entries\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":766,\\\"project\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\,\\\"name\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\,\\\"issue\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\%@\,\\\"user\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\,\\\"name\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\,\\\"activity\\\":\%@\{\\\"id\\\":\%@\,\\\"name\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\,\\\"hours\\\":\%@\,\\\"comments\\\":\%@\,\\\"spent_on\\\":\\\"%@\\\"\%@\}",,,...];
NSString * newstring1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@\"%@\"",newstring];
NSError *error=nil;
NSData * objectData = [newstring1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The log shows data values.
 But after this step,

```
NSDictionary * json= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:0 error:&error];
```

After serialization it shows null values.

```
NSLog(@"%@",error);
```

On  error message it show this.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7fe0faa73210
>   {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.}

on converting to dictionary.

What might be the error.How to rectify it?Please need guidance on this.Thanks for the help in advance. On doing statically it works,but dynamically creating this it shows error? how to rectify it?

Comment: Suggested to check your son string in http://jsonlint.com before parsing. You may get an idea where is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the **,** after the `activity` dictionary. I formatted the `JSON'.

```
{  
   "x":{  
      "user":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"a"
      },
      "startday":"2016-01-10",
      "status":"New",
      "total":1,
      "time_entries":[  
         {  
            "id":766,
            "project":{  
               "id":3,
               "name":"b"
            },
            "issue":{  
               "id":4
            },
            "user":{  
               "id":1,
               "name":"c"
            },
            "activity":{  
               "id":8,
               "name":"d"
            },
            "hours":1,
            "comments":"",
            "spent_on":"2016-01-10"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You need to check at your end there are many websites and add-ons. Suggested one is https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Chrome extention is: JSON Editor

Comment: {\"x\":{\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"a\"},\"startday\":\"2016-01-10\",\"status\":\"New\",\"total\":1.0,\"time_entries\":[{\"id\":766,\"project\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"a\"},\"issue\":{\"id\":4},\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"b\"},\"activity\":{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"c\"},\"hours\":1.0,\"comments\":\"\",\"spent_on\":\"2016-01-10\"}]}} if i put this like only in static data.....it gets serialized and shows the values.. i am not missing comma or something